# Address label print using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to print address labels on a address label sheet of 105*48.

I am not able to fit my content properly in those label boxes.Based on browser and printer setting content is getting printed differently. My End goal is to achieve something like below and this should look the same on print as well. Note no margins.

[image: address label]

Can you please suggest top best approach to achieve a uniform print of these labels across browsers.

Can we achieve this using simple HTML and CSS.

[EDIT]

Adding sample code ..

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
        body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }        }
    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.page {
    width: 21cm;
    min-height: 29.7cm;
    padding: 0cm;
    margin: auto;
    background: white;
    }

.box {
        display:block;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width:95mm;
        height:48mm;
        float:left;
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: top;
        border: 1px solid red;
        Padding:5mm;
    }

@page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 4mm 0 4mm 0 ;
}
@media print {
    .page {
        margin: 0;
        border: initial;
        border-radius: initial;
        width: initial;
        min-height: initial;
        box-shadow: initial;
        background: initial;
        page-break-after: always;
    }

}       
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page">
        <div class="box"><h2>Mr. TEST</h2><p>how are you</p></div>
        <div class="box"><h2>Mr. TEST</h2><p>how are you</p></div>      
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer is an extension of the excellent article on [Boulder Information Services](https://boulderinformationservices.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/print-avery-labels-using-css-and-html/) where they describe using css to print multi page labels, with leading blanks if necessary.  There is also a double-click feature to show/hide the outline of the labels.

```php
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 
        
    session_start();
    session_write_close();
    
    if ($_SESSION['user_customer_id']=="" || !isset($_SESSION['user_customer_id'])) {
        header("location:index.html");
        die();
    }
    
    $db = getConnection();
        
    $blnActive = (isset($_GET["active"]));
    $blnAll = (isset($_GET["all"]));
    $blanks = 0;
    if (isset($_GET["blanks"])) {
        $blanks = passed_var("blanks", "get");  //passed_var is a function that cleanses the GET parameter.
    }
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT pers.full_name, pers.first_name, pers.last_name, pers.full_address, pers.street, pers.suite, pers.city, pers.state, pers.zip
    FROM `cse_person` pers 
    WHERE pers.deleted = 'N'
    AND pers.customer_id = :customer_id
    ";
    
    $sql .= "
    ORDER BY TRIM(pers.full_name)
    ";
    //LIMIT 0, 10
    //die($sql);
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam("customer_id", $_SESSION['user_customer_id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $clients = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    
    $db = null;
    
    //die(print_r($clients));
    $arrStreets = array();
    if ($blanks > 0) {
        for($int = 0; $int < $blanks; $int++) {
            $arrStreets[] = "<span class='full_name'>&nbsp;</span><br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;";
        }
    }
    foreach ($clients as $client) {
        $street = $client->street;
        $city = $client->city;
        $suite = $client->suite;
        $state = $client->state;
        $zip = $client->zip;
        
        //nothing
         
        //name
        $full_name = $client->first_name . " " . $client->last_name;
        
        $full_name = str_replace("-", " - ", $full_name);   //so that ucwords works on hyphenated names
        $full_name = ucwords(strtolower($full_name));
        $full_name = str_replace(" - ", "-", $full_name);
        $arrStreets[] = "<span class='full_name'>" . $full_name . "</span><br>" . $street . "<br>" . $city . ", " . $state . " " . $zip;
    }
    
    $row_counter = 0;
    foreach($arrStreets as $street) {
        if (!isset($arrRow[$row_counter])) {
            $arrRow[$row_counter] = array();
        }
        $label = '<div class="label">' . $street . '</div>';
        $arrRow[$row_counter][] = $label;
        if (count($arrRow[$row_counter])==3) {
            //however, might be new page
            if (($row_counter%30)==0) {
                if ($row_counter != 0) {
                    $arrRow[$row_counter][2] .='
                    <div class="page-break">' . $row_counter . '</div>';
                }
            }
            $row_counter++;
        }
    }
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Avery Labels (5160) Report</title>
        <style>
        body {
            width: 8.5in;
            margin: 0in .1875in;
            }
        .label{
            /* Avery 5160 labels -- CSS and HTML by MM at Boulder Information Services */
            width: 2.025in; /* plus .6 inches from padding */
            height: .875in; /* plus .125 inches from padding */
            padding: .125in .3in 0;
            margin-right: .125in; /* the gutter */
    
            float: left;
            font-size:0.9em;
    
            text-align: left;
            overflow: hidden;
    
            outline: 1px white; /* outline doesn't occupy space like border does */
            }
        .page-break  {
            clear: left;
            display:block;
            page-break-after:always;
            }
        .full_name {
            font-size:1.1em;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
        </style>
    
    </head>
    <body ondblclick="showDotted()">
    <?php if ($blanks==0) { ?>
    <div id="blanks_link">
        If you have a partially printed sheet of labels, please <a href="javascript:enterBlanks()">click here to enter the number of blanks</a> you wish to skip.
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php foreach($arrRow as $row) {
        echo $row[0];
        if (isset($row[1])){
            echo $row[1];
        }
        if (isset($row[2])){
            echo $row[2];
        }
    }
    ?>
    
    
    <script language="javascript">
    var blnDotted = false;
    function showDotted() {
      var cols = document.getElementsByClassName('label');
      for(i=0; i<cols.length; i++) {
          if (!blnDotted) {
            cols[i].style.outline = '1px dotted';
          } else {
              cols[i].style.outline = '1px white';
          }
      }
      if (!blnDotted) {
          blnDotted = true;
      } else {
          blnDotted = false;
      }
    }
    function init() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            hideBlankLink();
        }, 3000);
    }
    function hideBlankLink() {
        document.getElementById("blanks_link").style.display = "none";
    }
    function enterBlanks() {
        var labels = prompt("Please enter the number of labels you want to skip to start", "0");
    
        if (labels != null) {
            document.location.href = "multi_labels.php?<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>&blanks=" + labels;
        }
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>

Just in case you need it, here is the getConnection function:

    function getConnection() {
        $dbhost = "YOURHOST";
        $dbuser="YOURUSER";
        $dbpass="YOURPWD";
        $dbname="YOURDB";
        
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);            
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $dbh;
    }
```

Comment: This is very helpful code. It is useful to know that the CSS doesn't assume border-box sizing, so if your site uses border-box (as with bootstrap 3+), you'll need to account for that in the .label size and padding.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use PHP, then you can use something like [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) which will allow you to create a "print" button which, when clicked, will simply pump out a PDF of the labels you desire.  This will work across all browsers and printers, and allow you to be specific, right down to the inch, or millimeter.

Using pure CSS and HTML will never give you the desired results as every browsers/device/whatever have different specs on how they interpret padding/font size/margin/etc.

I have worked with FPDF before, so if you get stuck, let me know.

Comment: Hello @Daniel, Do we have Java equivalent of the FPDF?

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/borisbrodski/Java-FPDF and this: https://github.com/nkiraly/Java-FPDF.  I've never worked with either, but they seem to be direct ports of the original, so documentation should be similar.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be adding a specific media query for the printing part:

```
@media print { 
 ....
}
```

If you would add some code, or a working fiddle, our help might be more effective...

Comment: I have added some code piece. This works fine in IE 11 but Chrome, firefox and Safari is giving trouble.